# ruby / middleman noob, path issue when starting middleman on branch

Tags: ruby, middleman

I have a middleman server running fine on the trunk part of my repository.
when I try to start middleman  on a branch, I get the following error:

Guard is now watching at '/Users/name.lastname/Foo/foo-html/branches/foo-html-1.2/src/main/resources/assets'
/Users/name.lastname/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/middleman-2.0.15.3/lib/middleman/core_extensions/features.rb:82:in `class_eval': cannot load such file -- helpers/application_helper (LoadError)

I use terminal to get to the relevant folder and use "bundle exec middleman". It looks like a path issue, something relative to the current directory when I run that command. What files should I look at to edit middleman's settings ?

Comment: I know this question is not very SO style, but I thought its an easyone, just some path I change from "/foo/bar" to "./foo/bar". The folder in branch contains gemfile and config.rb just like the one in trunk. I hope someone can indicate me what to look at.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that probably wont help anyone, but i had to comment out a few lines in config.rb, located in the root of the branch tree. like this :

```
# require 'helpers/application_helper'
# activate :application_helper
```